# SVN commit error

Tags: svn

Please, help me out,

I deleted my project file from the repository, Then I Tried to add the same file to the repository, but it gives me error that "File already under version control" I am not getting what's going wrong, I tried to change the file Name but no effect of that. This File is the Mac XCodeProject file.

Any help appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Can you give us the detail of your removal? How you did? 'svn del' or just an 'rm' of the file?

Comment: you could as well "accept" the correct answer as your question has been resolved...

Answer (score 2):

You might have manually deleted the file/project from the repo, but the .svn folder contains info about the repository and it doesn't know if you have deleted that file/project unless you used

```
svn delete yourProjectName
```

use this command to delete that file, so the .svn folder gets updated and you are all set :)

Comment: And not only that, but you need to `svn commit` your delete as well.

Comment: Thanks, For replying, I fixed this issue, Thanks again for your fast reply.

Comment: @ Praveen : its nice that the problem got resolved :) .. also read others answers as well, they will give some more insights .. :)
@ Greg : Thanks for the follow up .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do the next steps to avoid any problem

```
svn update
svn delete thefile
svn commit
```

In this way you'll get the file back in case you manually deleted it. Then you'll delete it properly and commit the change

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the file was deleted in the repository?  You may have deleted it locally without committing the change. To verify:

```
svn log url/to/file // or
svn list url/to/directory
```